# R: rbind two dataframes ordered by ID

Tags: r, dplyr, rbind

so I´m having a little trouble creating a new dataset by row-binding two "subsets" of an original datasets. I have implemented the following code, and it works fine. However it adds the rows of the second "subset" below the ones of the first "subset and doesn´t take into account the IDs.

```
rbind(df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(Var1 >= 
  ((max(Var1)/100)*95)),
  V_Dem_tracker_autocracies %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(first_equal_to(Var2, 1)))
```

so what I get is the data structured like this:

```
ID   Var2
1     0
1     0
1     0
2     0
2     0
2     0
1     1
2     1
```

however I would want it like this:

```
ID   Var2
1     0
1     0
1     0
1     1
2     0
2     0
2     0
2     1
```

is there an easy solution getting to this? I appreciate all answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append arrange() to your pipe to wrap the new bound data frame.

```
rbind(df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(Var1 >= ((max(Var1)/100)*95)),
  V_Dem_tracker_autocracies %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(first_equal_to(Var2, 1))) %>%
  arrange(ID)
```

If the order is incorrect, you can use desc(ID).